# Changing Chart Line Color not Working

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to change the Line color of chart in excel with C# and it's not working. I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373130/how-to-do-i-change-a-series-color-in-excel-using-c) but it just doesn't work at all.

The graph is displayed correctly with the correct value but the color is the default blue one from excel.

Here is my code for the graph

```
ChartObject chartObject = excelIndicateur.addChart();
chartObject.Chart.SetSourceData(fullDataRange);
SeriesCollection sc = chartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection();
Series s = sc.Item(1);
s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(chartColor);
chartObject.Chart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
```

Comment: Try experimenting with different properties... From memory, i thinks its the outline colour or possibly Background colour...

Comment: At the moment I tried `ForeColor`, `BackColor`, Also `Border.Interior` and I keep going, I will get back if I found out

Comment: Also maybe set the ChartType first... Right after you instantiate it...

Comment: Ok I got it I used `s.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(chartColor);` and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you set the `ChartType` first the problem goes away.
The default `ChartType` is Column which has the Border propety. When you change it to a Line `ChartType`, the Border properties are moved to the Line. If you set the `ChartType` to Line first then ForeColor will work and your code will be cleaner.

Comment: I tried to put the type first and keeping where I originally put it and both worked

Comment: Oh well then I will try this as soon as possible. But thanks for the help about the type I didn't know it was dynamic and that it will changed the behaviour of the property.

Comment: Well, first of all, there needs to be a default ChartType and then it needs to behave rationally when the user changes the chart type, so the properties of the bar chart series (which is the default type) needs to be transformed into the properties of the new type. The ChartFormat object has a Line and a Fill property. In the default, Bar Chart, the Line property applies to the Border, in the Line Type... See what I mean?

Comment: So for the BarChart Line and Border will both apply to the same things?

Comment: Yes. But, to be honest @PeterFour, its really doesn't matter... the main point is to establish the ChartType before you start setting properties. If you do that then it will behave rationally.

Comment: I understand yes, it also make the code more understandable and logical rather than defining things in a weird order

Answer (score 0):

For those interested about how to make this work,I did some test with all the property and it finally worked with

```
s.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(chartColor);
```